# Encrypt a data input in an Android App and decrypt it in different database engines (SQL Server, MS Access)

Tags: android, sql-server, sqlite, ms-access, encryption

Hello:

I received a special requirement today and it consists in the following situation:

From now, we have to encrypt 4 inputs in our Android app and then, when this data is already in the Server (SQL Server), these fields must be decrypted there when necessary and the same for the Microsoft Access engine.

I was reading about encrypting some fields in an Android app that I can use some encryption algorithms... okey, but do I can use the same algorithm for decryption in SQL Server and Ms Access?

What algorithm can I choose in order to don't have problems in the other db engines later when decrypting?

Can you suggest me another alternative maybe?
Hope I can find a light

Thks a lot and blessings

Comment: Why decrypt the data in the database? Why not decrypt it in the web application?

Comment: Yes, I have been reading that these encryption/decryption operations should not be done in the db layer... but I don't see the "because of" part ... So maybe I can sound a little bit dumb asking this, but why not?

Answer (score 0):

You may use any asymmetric algorithm, supported by Java.
There is a [full example](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-asymmetric-cryptography-example/) of using RSA for encryption and decryption using key pairs.

Comment: Thks for your suggestion . Now I'm also considering a symmetric one like AES

Comment: In your case symmetric encryption is not a proper point. Better to have different keys to encrypt and decrypt data.